# Calculating number of overlapping days between two date ranges

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to calculate the number of days that overlap between two date ranges.

- **Date range #1:** the interval between a participant's enrollment date and enrollment date + 180 days.
- **Date range #2:** the interval containing all "winter" months (October 1 - May 31).

I have ~200 rows of data. Each row has a date value for `enr_dte`. I have created a variable called `end_dte` which is `enr_dte + days(180)`.

I have tried using `difftime` for this. My current code gives me the correct answer as long as the time interval does not completely span the summer period or does not include time after the summer period. If it does, then I default to 180 days of overlap.

I'm open to using other packages/functions to achieve this.

```
#This variable is used to change the end of the winter season depending on the end_dte
OMset <- OMset %>%
  mutate(winter_end = case_when(
    ymd(end_dte) >= ymd("2022-10-01") ~ ymd("2023-05-31"),
    ymd(end_dte) < ymd("2022-10-01") ~ ymd("2022-05-31")
  ))

OMset <- OMset %>%
  mutate(overlap_days = difftime(pmin(ymd(end_dte), ymd(winter_end)), pmax(ymd(enr_dte), ymd("2021-10-01")), units = "days")) %>%
  mutate(overlap_days = as.numeric(overlap_days))
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(Onset[20,])`?

Comment: If you cannot share any of your data, you could also create a fake data set with dates that represent the issues you are having.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. The below response with the lubridate code worked well. Next time I will create a fake dataset and upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `lubridate` package to create intervals and then calculate the length of the intersection between the intervals.

It's unclear what you mean by "the interval containing all "winter" months ". Does this include `[2021-10-01 , 2022-05-31]`, `[2022-10-01 , 2023-05-31]`, `[2023-10-01 , 2024-05-31]` etc.?
Here is an example using some randomly generated dates from between January 1 2022 and June 30 2023, where I have assumed that "winter months" = `[2022-10-01 , 2023-05-31]`:

```
# Generate random dates:
dat <- data.frame( enr_dte = sample( seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2023-06-30'), by="day"), 10) )

dat %>% 
  mutate( 
    # Create interval between enrollment and enrollment + 180 days:
    enr_end_int = lubridate::interval( enr_dte, enr_dte + days(180) )
    # Create winter interval:
    , winter_int = lubridate::interval( as.Date('2022-10-01'), as.Date('2023-05-31') )
    # Get the intersection between enrollment interval and winter interval:
    , enr_winter_intersection = lubridate::intersect( enr_end_int, winter_int )
    # Get the length of the intersection (int_length can only return length in seconds):
    , enr_winter_intersection_length_sec = lubridate::int_length( enr_winter_intersection )
    # Convert seconds to days:
    , enr_winter_intersection_length_days = enr_winter_intersection_length_sec/60/60/24
  )
```

This resulted in the following:

```
      enr_dte                    enr_end_int                     winter_int        enr_winter_intersection enr_winter_intersection_length_sec enr_winter_intersection_length_days
1  2023-01-24 2023-01-24 UTC--2023-07-23 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2023-01-24 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                           10972800                                 127
2  2022-09-24 2022-09-24 UTC--2023-03-23 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-03-23 UTC                           14947200                                 173
3  2022-03-12 2022-03-12 UTC--2022-09-08 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                         NA--NA                                 NA                                  NA
4  2022-10-14 2022-10-14 UTC--2023-04-12 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2022-10-14 UTC--2023-04-12 UTC                           15552000                                 180
5  2022-10-04 2022-10-04 UTC--2023-04-02 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2022-10-04 UTC--2023-04-02 UTC                           15552000                                 180
6  2022-08-07 2022-08-07 UTC--2023-02-03 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-02-03 UTC                           10800000                                 125
7  2023-04-14 2023-04-14 UTC--2023-10-11 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2023-04-14 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                            4060800                                  47
8  2023-03-20 2023-03-20 UTC--2023-09-16 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2023-03-20 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                            6220800                                  72
9  2023-05-07 2023-05-07 UTC--2023-11-03 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC 2023-05-07 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                            2073600                                  24
10 2022-01-04 2022-01-04 UTC--2022-07-03 UTC 2022-10-01 UTC--2023-05-31 UTC                         NA--NA                                 NA                                  NA
```

Comment: There's a problem with overlapping years in your version: see row 3, which has NA as result, but it overlaps with the 2022 winter months. Not sure if the OP is only looking for 2023 winter months, or any and all winter months

Comment: You're right @ChristophSafferling. The OP was not clear on exactly which winter months they were interested in. I assumed, based on OP's wording, that **Date range #2** = [ 2022-10-01, 2023-05-31 ].

Comment: Hi, thank you both. The lubridate code works very well. Apologies for not being clear - I did, in fact, want to use all winter months. For my dataset, this only included 2021-2023, so it was easy to duplicate the above code and sum it to get a total # of overlapping days between seasons. Though I imagine there are more elegant ways to do that, especially when you have larger #'s of years.

Comment: With a dataset of ~200 you don't need to look for efficiency :) One thing I noticed: since your winter months are so long (~240 days), your enrollment days are guaranteed to overlap at least on  one side. So I think you could check if the start/end dates are in the winter months and then just calculate the length of min(start date, enr), min(end date, enr+180)

Comment: Dammit, I can't edit my comment... it should be max(winter_start, enr), min(winter_end, enr+180), of course!